# Send mail with multiple attachment using Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm using Microsoft-Graph API version 1.4 and trying to send mail with attachment using following code..

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

Message message = new Message();
message.subject = "Meet for lunch?";
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;
body.content = "The new cafeteria is open.";
message.body = body;
LinkedList<Recipient> toRecipientsList = new LinkedList<Recipient>();
Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
emailAddress.address = "meganb@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;
LinkedList<Attachment> attachmentsList = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
FileAttachment attachments = new FileAttachment();
attachments.name = "attachment.txt";
attachments.contentType = "text/plain";
attachments.contentBytes = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh";
attachmentsList.add(attachments);
message.attachments = attachmentsList;

graphClient.me()
    .sendMail(message,null)
    .buildRequest()
    .post();
```

Ref.Link: [Graph-Send-Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

But, message.attachments requires AttachmentCollectionPage object not LinkedList();

Can anyone help me to send a mail with multiple attachment.

Thanks

Comment: i remember a related old thread. Please see if this helps  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602529/microsoft-graph-adding-multiple-attachments-to-an-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to send multiple attachment in a single mail using 1.4.0 version. Checkout the following code...

```
val address = EmailAddress()
address.address = "vivek@domain.com"
val recipient = Recipient()
recipient.emailAddress = address

val message = MyMessage()
message.subject = "Test E-Mail"
message.body = getItemBody()
message.toRecipients = Collections.singletonList(recipient)

val att = FileAttachment()
att.contentBytes = File("/home/user/file.pdf").readBytes()
att.contentType = "text/pdf"
att.name = "file.pdf"
att.oDataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"

val att2 = FileAttachment()
att2.contentBytes = "hello there! from second file".toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
att2.contentType = "text/plain"
att2.name = "hi2.txt"
att2.oDataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"

message.addAttachment(att)
message.addAttachment(att2)

graphClient.me()
.sendMail(message,false)
.buildRequest()
.post();
```

The above code can be used to send multiple attachments with size less than 4 MB. To send above the limit please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262929/email-with-multiple-attachments-using-graph-api-4-mb/64263205#64263205).