# Sending emails from Azure functions (which will be consumed by Snowflake procedures) without using any third party API like SendGrid

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-notificationhub

Is there any way to send emails (Organization/Domain based not Gmail) from Azure Functions without using any kind of Third Party API's like SendGrid or mailGun,

Actually, I am looking for these Azure functions to be called from Snowflake External functions so that my procedures can trigger. I found few questions related to these with AWS SNS but am looking for Azure Tech stack and unfortunately, we know that azure notification hub doesn't provide email functionality, unlike AWS SNS.

Comment: Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-send-messages) or [Logic Apps](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/03/add-email-notification-in-azure-data.html) in order to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Could you please share any source which uses Graph API in azure functions for email, (I am still not convinced as Graph API's core functionality is not sending emails and also learnt it as restrictions in email attachments)
coming to logic apps, we are using sql agents for schedulings, so, not planning to switch from it though it supports emails and schedules

Comment: Sure @Santhosh you can find how to send the email from graph API from [HERE](https://jeremythake.com/using-azure-functions-with-the-microsoft-graph-and-bing-translator-apis-379510306477) and how to solve the [attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) restrictions in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262929/email-with-multiple-attachments-using-graph-api-4-mb).

Comment: Thanks for the references @SwethaKandikonda-MT, could you also share any references for azure functions calling GraphAPI - if possible written in python, the link you shared seems it is on Translator API